# why does enum initialize from integer with copy initialization?

Tags: c++, enums, initialization

A variable of `enum` type may not be initialized with an integer. However, copy initialization with an integer seems to work, why is that?

```
enum Day {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday};

int main(){
   Day today=Day(1); // this line compiles
   Day today(1);     // this line does not
}
```

Comment: `Day(1)` is a function-style cast. It does the same thing as `(Day)1`.

Comment: so, it is not a constructor?

Comment: It's not really a constructor. It just looks like one, so you can use it in a template - `T(1)` works even if `T` is not a class.

Comment: Enumerated types don't have constructors. So, no, it's not a constructor. <g>

Answer (score 2):

`Day(1)` is a functional-style explicit cast because it uses parentheses and exactly one expression between them. This means it is equivalent to `(Day)1`.

Both do not directly initialize an object of type `Day`. Instead they try different explicit casts. In particular the first cast attempted is a `static_cast`. This `static_cast` will succeed since an integral type can be converted to the enumeration type via `static_cast`.

So the initialization is equivalent to

```
Day today = static_cast<Day>(1);
```

The variable `today` is then copy-initialized from the `Day` prvalue resulting from the conversion.

You can see that this is not a property of copy-initialization itself since

```
Day today = 1;
```

which copy-initializes directly from `1`, doesn't work. Similarly `Day today = Day{1};` doesn't work, because the form `Day{1}` is not a functional-style explicit cast and will instead direct-initialize a `Day` object from `1`, which isn't allowed either (which is why `Day today(1);` doesn't work as well).